# REST calls to multiple services - Howto approach this? (NodeJS)

Tags: json, node.js, database, rest, mysqli

I need to make periodic REST calls to about 4-6 different services, periodically, every around 10 minutes, and I'm not entirely sure on how I should approach this.

Originally, I wanted to to make all the calls from a single file, but after some thinking I realized maybe I should separate each client to it's own file, and have just one client run them all individually, instead of having it all as one big code.

This could make troubleshooting easier, and management a LOT easier, as everything is separated and kept to it's own.

Is this the best approach to this sort of problem?

Also, a bit unrelated; REST calls from all sources should, at the end, be put into a database, however I'm not sure which "database scheme" (is that the word) I should go with.
Should Everything be put into a JSON file, or maybe a MySQL database? (I dont know if MySQL is the best approach, as at the end all data will be structured the same, so there will really be only 1 table) Or maybe a database scheme I'm unfamiliar with.

looking forward to your responses.

edit: also, I should mention, the database will be reasonably large.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a rest call, which should run without disturbing UI thread, you can prefer using **WEB WORKERS**, Since it run as background script it will not affect the performance of the page.